# torque calculation issues

Tags: mobile-robot

so i have been trying to draw a free body diagram of a 6 axis robot arm project, in order to know the torque required for each joint. and now am confused about the angular acceleration part which contributes to the amount of torque needed. i was simply using the force times distance to get the torque right from the end effector of the robot arm to the base, but i realised soon, that the base motor would not work with the same formula because it have a CW and CCW movement(angular movement), which causes some acceleration,which in turn affect the torque.
so how do i calculate precisely the torque for the base motor, to avoid any problems later.
the requirements are LENGTH: 1.5m    PAYLOAD : 20kg

Comment: Hi @Kwabena Reuben welcome to the Robotics Stack Exchange. I read through your question and it needs more information to be able to effectively help you. It's clear what answer will solve your problem. Please see [our guide to asking good questions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist) and update your question with more information.

Comment: A free body diagram is not the right way to go. Joint torques are related to end effector forces through the Jacobian. You'll also want to start looking into forward & inverse dynamics.